# Incomplete typedefs in libgit2

Tags: c, libgit2

I am trying to integrate `libgit2` (1.5.0) into my project. The compilation failes due to missing type definitions.

The **CMakeLists.txt** of my project includes the `include` directory and the `libgit2.a` file:

```cmake
target_include_directories(myprj PUBLIC ../libgit2/src/libgit2-1.5.0/include)

set(myprj "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libgit2.a")
link_directories(myprj ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
target_link_libraries(myprj PUBLIC ${libgit} crypto ssl)
```

The following code is a simplified version of the code I am using, but it should demonstrate the problem:

```c
#include <git2.h>


git_reference *ref;
git_branch_t btype;

int code = git_branch_next(&ref, &btype, iterator);
if(code != 0)
    return code;

char* name = ref->name;
```

The compiler fails with the error:

```text
error: invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘git_reference’
char* name = ref->name
                ^~
```

The `include` directory defines the type but the stuct itself is defined in the `src` directory only.

**libgit2-1.5.0/include/git2/types.h** ([source](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/main/include/git2/types.h))

```c
typedef struct git_reference git_reference;
```

**libgit2-1.5.0/src/libgit2/refs.h**([source](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/main/src/libgit2/refs.h))

```c
struct git_reference {
//...
};
```

I have tried to fix it by importing the `src` dir into my project but this doesnt work because of missing includes.

Import in Cmake:

```cmake
target_include_directories(myprj PUBLIC ../libgit2/src/libgit2-1.5.0/src/libgit2)
```

Error:

```text
libgit2/src/libgit2-1.5.0/src/libgit2/common.h:10:10: fatal error: git2_util.h: File or directory not found
   10 | #include "git2_util.h"
```

Comment: Hi they call this an "opaque type" in computing language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is on purpose, to make `git_reference` an opaque type. It can then be changed at will by the library authors without breaking compatibility.

To get the name of a reference, use [`git_reference_name`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/reference/git_reference_name) instead of accessing the field directly:

```
const char* name = git_reference_name(ref);
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution applies to most types in `gitlib2`.